# How to migrate changes in SQLite file into an existing app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've submitted an iOS app with `SQLite` database file to store data inside the app.

Now in next version of the app – I have some modifications in a database file.

Like,

1. Added new tables (1 empty, 2 with fixed data)
2. Added new columns in a table
3. Removed existing columns from a table

What, I thinking?

> I'll add a new database file (which included all changes) in my app, at first run of the app (after update) I'll check for the existence of an old database file, if available, will append everything from old to new file and lastly will delete the old file.

Is this the right way or there can be a more significant way like Core Data migration Or other more appropriate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if exists a right way, but my experience in this case, was to create a sql migration script and control the database version with pragma user_version of the sqlite.

Edit:
My app has three database changes, then I have three sql migration scripts. When the app is started exists a `if` to check the database user_version, then I apply the needed scripts for the database update.

In this scripts, I create the new tables, I get information of the old table, I insert the data in the recently created tables and in the end of script I set the user_version:

`//this number is the version of database: 1, 2, 3...
PRAGMA user_version = 2;`.

To know which version the user has, I do the query `PRAGMA user_version;`.

I hope this can help you.

EDIT2: Field "login" added in USER table:

```
//Create the new table
CREATE TABLE user_new (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    login TEXT,
    name TEXT
);

//Get data of older table
INSERT INTO user_new
    SELECT
        id,
        null AS login,
        name
    FROM
        user;

//Delete te older table
DROP TABLE user;

//Rename the new table
ALTER TABLE user_new RENAME TO user;

//Set database version
PRAGMA user_version = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you able to elaborate more on this?

Comment: Thank you for a deep info, I want to clear one thing, how to set user_version in `SQLite` file? Also, can you edit your answer with those scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Core data migration is a completely different thing. But if you want to modify the SQLite database you can either

1. Replace the old file
2. Change the SQL DB Structure by query.

Comment: Thanks, however this is what I'm aware of but still I'm looking for some more significant way to get this done.