# SQLite database - Add new columns but user has to uninstall & reinstall app

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I have an app live on the store. It has a library of recipes. If I add a new column to the database such as "nutritional info". What is the best way to add a new column without user having to uninstall then reinstall.

```
- (CEVORecipe *) getRecipe:(NSInteger *)id
{
    CEVORecipe *recipe = [[CEVORecipe alloc] init];

    if ([self open])
    {
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT rowid,* FROM arecipes WHERE rowid=\"%d\"",(int)id];

        const char *stmt = [sql UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database,stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                NSInteger rowid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

//                section,name,image,servings,difficulty,preparation_time,instructions,ingredients,photos

                NSInteger section = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSString *image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                NSInteger servings = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
                NSInteger difficulty = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);
                NSInteger preparation_time = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6);
                NSString *instructions = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];
                NSString *ingredients = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];

                NSString *macros = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];
                NSString *creator = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];
                NSString *profile = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)];
             NSString *diet = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 12)];

                NSArray *photoJson = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13)] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];



                NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


                for(NSString *photo in photoJson){
                    if(![photo isEqualToString:@""]){
                        [photos addObject:photo];                        
                    }
                }


                recipe = [[CEVORecipe alloc] initWithData:rowid :section :name :image :&servings :&difficulty :&preparation_time :instructions :ingredients :macros :creator :profile :diet :photos];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            [self close];
        }
    }
```

Comment: try solutions provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios

Comment: Seems like migration is a thing what are you looking for. Please, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607487/how-to-migrate-changes-in-sqlite-file-into-an-existing-app